# Tomcat8 SSL query

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat8, tls1.2

I have Tomcat8 installed on an Ubuntu Server 16.04TLS.

I wish to enable SSL/TLS to ensure my users (website) are well protected from network attackers, such as people monitoring the connection.

I was considering getting an SSL certificate buy either buying one for $9, generating my own, or using a service such as letsencrypt.

Question: What is the difference between enabling SSL Tomcat server.xml file, and using an SSL certificate? Are there any benefits to one over the other?

I believe from my reading that enabling SSL encrypts the connection, however using a certificate means when users visit site they get HTTPS padlock in browser bar?

I am still pretty new to all of this though. Would rather not spend money buying a cert and having to renew letsencrypt everyday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL has two main functions: secure authentication and secure communication.
By configuring tomcat to work through https - you already have the secure communication. All the traffic will be encrypted.

If you also want secure authentication, meaning - make sure that when a user visited your site, he has a way of knowing it really is *your* site, then you will have to use certificates.

But such a certificate is worthless if it's not signed by a known trusted source. In other words, if you put on the site a self-signed certificate, it is signed by an unknown source and then the browser will show the warning.

So to conclude:
If you just want to encrypt - just set server.xml accordingly.
If you want a valid certificate (users can click the small padlock icon and get certificate domain info) - buy from a valid certificate authority

Comment: Could I enable SSL with Tomcat and then also use a certificate too? I know it's overkill though. Also, how do people with hidden services manage to buy certificates?

Comment: If you want to use a certificate you *must* configure your server to work through https. Two of the parameters of a connector are the location of the keystore (keystoreFile) that holds the certificate and the alias of the certificate in that keystore (keyAlias). If you'll configure those parameters then the server will use them.